# cron doesn't execute any task, but writes into log as executed

Tags: centos, cron

I have strange problem on one of my servers. Cron does not execute any task, but it writes to its log, that task has been executed successfully. Like some simulation mode is activated...

```
Apr 30 03:03:08 nd-10049 crond[13387]: (root) CMD (php /usr/local/frb/backup.php)
Apr 30 03:05:01 nd-10049 crond[13397]: (root) CMD (php /home/support/public_html/cron/cron_hourly.php>/home/support/public_html/cron/hourly.log)
Apr 30 03:09:01 nd-10049 crond[19108]: (root) CMD (/etc/webmin/cron/tempdelete.pl )
Apr 30 03:10:01 nd-10049 crond[19467]: (root) CMD (php /home/support/public_html/cron/cron_hourly.php>/home/support/public_html/cron/hourly.log)
Apr 30 03:14:44 nd-10049 crontab[21154]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Apr 30 03:15:01 nd-10049 crond[21309]: (root) CMD (php /home/support/public_html/cron/cron_hourly.php>/home/support/public_html/cron/hourly.log)
Apr 30 03:15:38 nd-10049 crontab[21154]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Apr 30 03:15:38 nd-10049 crontab[21154]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Apr 30 03:16:01 nd-10049 crond[14961]: (root) RELOAD (cron/root)
Apr 30 03:20:02 nd-10049 crond[22620]: (root) CMD (php /home/support/public_html/cron/cron_hourly.php)
```

There are no errors about cron in common log (messages). The OS is CentOS. What can I do to check what is the problem? What can the problem be?

Comment: Cron daemon is vixie-cron

Comment: Try creating a `cron` job using something other than `php` as a test. Use something like `* * * * * root date >> /tmp/crontest.out`. Otherwise, you need to give more information about what's happening, not happening, supposed to happen, the content of the scripts is, etc.

Comment: OMG :) That was simple. php was not on system's PATH. Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG :) That was simple. php was not on system's PATH. Simple

Answer (score 1):

Try with **/usr/bin/php** instead of **php**.